# Static Library linked Program VS Source Code Compiled program huge size difference

Tags: c++, static, size, crypto++

I have a library (Crypto++) its almost 50MB in total when the library is compiled.

I took the source code of Crypto++ and only added the source files of the algorithms that I am going to use on my application.
I then created the application and decided to compile Crypto++ as a static library and linked it to a cloned version of the same project.

So now I have 2 projects:

Project 1: Has only the necessary source files to compile and use only the algorithms I need AES,SHA256,etc.

Project 2: Has only the header files and the Crypto++ linked static lib.

Now, When I compile both projects, I was supposed (or I always thought) to see that both exes have the same size since the linker will only link the source I am using in Project 2 into the exe, basically It would link exactly the same files that I am using on Project 1.
But this is not the case, I see a huge difference of Project 1 vs Project 2...
The project that uses the static library is 6.2 times bigger than the project that was compiled with the source code.(Both compiled in Release mode)

Project 1 (source) size: 210kb
Project 2 (static lib) size: 1,303kb

Why is this? I always though the linker was supposed to only use what I'm referencing on my code. Is this just a linker inefficiency?

Can some one enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

The linker will only use what it referenced. The behavior that you are observing is a direct result of the fact that the entire crypto library is built as one object. The linker has no choice but to include the whole thing. The linker could do what you are expecting if you had the source code for library and built it along side your project.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a library (Crypto++) its almost 50MB in total when the library is compiled....

Yes, the static library carries around all the symbols. Nothing can be discarded because it may be needed.

It also carries around debug information if you used `-g`. Some optimization flags will affect it too. For example `-Os` minimizes for code size.

---

> The project that uses the static library is 6.2 times bigger than the project that was compiled with the source code. Why is this?

We need to see your program, and your compiler and linker switches to better explain what's going on. Based on these numbers, I'm guessing some dead code stripping is occurring, but not as much as you expect:

> Project 1 (source) size: 210kb Project 2 (static lib) size: 1,303kb

---

> I always though the linker was supposed to only use what I'm referencing on my code. Is this just a linker inefficiency?

When building the Crypto++ library, use the `make lean` recipe. It adds function sections (`-ffunction-sections`) and data sections (`-fdata-sections`) so the linker can do a better job at discarding unused code and data. Also see [GNUmakefile | Makefile Targets](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GNUmakefile#Makefile_Targets) on the Crypto++ wiki.

When you link your application use the appropriate linker switch. With GCC/LD, that would be `-Wl,--gc-sections`. Under Apple/DYLD, that would be `-Wl,-dead_strip`.

---

You can also strip debug symbols, which will reduce the binary size even further. Its not clear to me if your built with symbols or stripped them afterwards.

If you strip and discard the symbols altogether, then the stack traces will be mostly useless. If you retain the symbols in an offline file, then you might be able to make sense of a stack trace. Also see [Debug Symbols](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Debug_Symbols) on the Crypto++ wiki.

---

Here are the results from investigating the `lean` target for users. Also see ['make lean' target?](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/SaORS7dHSZ0/xBcCGs5cEQAJ) on the Crypto++ user group.

***Test program***:

```c++
int main( int, char** ) {

  Integer j("100000000000000000000000000000000");
  j %= 1999;

  cout << "j: " << j << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

***Lean*** (library built with `make lean`, program linked with `-Wl,--gc-sections`):

```
$ ls -l integer.exe
-rwx------  1 jwalton  staff  162012 Jan  4 13:00 integer.exe
```

***Normal*** (library built with `make`, no special linker switches):

```
$ ls -l integer.exe
-rwx------  1 jwalton  staff  2636952 Jan  4 13:02 integer.exe
```

---

The `lean` target was added after Crypto++ 5.6.3 was released. You will need to fetch the code from Master if you want it:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp
```

Or, you can apply the patch below to the GNUmakefile by hand from [Commit 9696b9e5e79ff18a](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/9696b9e5e79ff18a30956467497e757562e26310). Add it around line 270 or so:

```
+# Dead code stripping. Issue 'make lean'.
+ifeq ($(findstring lean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),lean)
+ifeq ($(findstring -ffunction-sections,$(CXXFLAGS)),)
+CXXFLAGS += -ffunction-sections
+endif # CXXFLAGS
+ifeq ($(findstring -fdata-sections,$(CXXFLAGS)),)
+CXXFLAGS += -fdata-sections
+endif # CXXFLAGS
+ifneq ($(IS_DARWIN),0)
+ifeq ($(findstring -Wl,-dead_strip,$(LDFLAGS)),)
+LDFLAGS += -Wl,-dead_strip
+endif # CXXFLAGS
+else # BSD, Linux and Unix
+ifeq ($(findstring -Wl,--gc-sections,$(LDFLAGS)),)
+LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
+endif # LDFLAGS
+endif # MAKECMDGOALS
+endif # Dead code stripping
```

And the following where the recipes are:

```
+.PHONY: lean
+lean: libcryptopp.a cryptest.exe
+
```